# How to scroll QLabel?

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to implement Picture Zoom In/Out and Picture Scroll on *Meego/Qt/QML*.

I have written a class A which is inherited from *QLabel*.

```
A::A( "parent" )
{
  setAlignment();
  setGeometry();
  setScaledContents();
}
```

Now I have a Controller class B. This class is responsible to handle the events from *QML* to the my Class A. In my controller class I have instantiate in the following way.

```
B :: B()
{
 a = new A();
 proxyWidget = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();
 proxyWidget->setWidget(a); 
}
```

Since this is a *QML* based application I am handling events from QML.

For Zoom I have used `PinchArea`. Whenever I am getting `PinchUpdated` event I am setting the `setGeometry`of the *QLabel* accordingly. I am zooming in and zooming out.

For scroll I have used `MouseArea` with `onPositionChanged` event. However I am unable to scroll the label event after calling the scroll API of the *QLabel*.

Can someone please tell me where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to zoom using mouse scroll for instance.

I am not good at `QML` but you certainly should be handling [wheel events](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwheelevent.html) in your class `A`. It is not clear for me if every Qt event has a QML equivalent, but you can always put C++ code. The function to implement is :

```
 virtual void wheelEvent ( QWheelEvent * event );
```

You have the [delta](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwheelevent.html#delta) variable which can be useful to determine the speed of zoom (using delta absolute value) and whether it should grow or shrink (using sign of delta)

Comment: Zoom is working fine. My problem is with scrolling. If I create a scroll area it is showing scroll bar which I don't want and I need to use scroll bar to scroll it . I need drag on the screen and QLabel should move which is not happening. I have used scroll api but it doesn't work

Comment: you still need to use wheel events. But I am going to update this answer. So you want to change which portion of the image is displayed when the user scroll?